# How to stop css3 animation at the end?

Tags: css, css-animations

Im playing around with css3 translateY and i'm not abel to stop the animation at the end.

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav-ctn">
    <li><a href="?type=about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="?type=projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="?type=media">Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="?type=schedule">Schedule</a></li>
    <li><a href="?type=contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
    .tr-up {
        -moz-animation: tr-up 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -o-animation: tr-up 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-animation: tr-up 0.5s ease-in-out;
        animation: tr-up 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }


    @-moz-keyframes tr-up {
        from {
            -moz-transform: translateY(0);
            -ms-transform: translateY(0);
            -o-transform: translateY(0);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
        }

        to {
            -moz-transform: translateY(-3px);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-3px);
            -o-transform: translateY(-3px);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
            transform: translateY(-3px);
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes tr-up {
        from {
            -moz-transform: translateY(0);
            -ms-transform: translateY(0);
            -o-transform: translateY(0);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
        }

        to {
            -moz-transform: translateY(-3px);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-3px);
            -o-transform: translateY(-3px);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
            transform: translateY(-3px);
        }
    }

    @keyframes tr-up {
        from {
            -moz-transform: translateY(0);
            -ms-transform: translateY(0);
            -o-transform: translateY(0);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
        }

        to {
            -moz-transform: translateY(-3px);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-3px);
            -o-transform: translateY(-3px);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
            transform: translateY(-3px);
        }
    }
```

So far i have tried the solution form the following posts:

[Stopping CSS3 KeyFrames Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038803/stopping-css3-keyframes-animation)

[Stop CSS3 animation jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758969/stop-css3-animation-jumping)

[Animation stop with css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928711/animation-stop-with-css3)

[Stopping a CSS3 Animation on last frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359627/stopping-a-css3-animation-on-last-frame)

But non of them worked for me.
So what i am doing wrong?

[HERES THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/mL6cw4at/)

Note: the `tr-up` class is dynamically added to the link characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animations [shouldn't work on inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements) so you need to change the default display property of the `<span>` tags to `span{display:inline-block;}` :

If you want to keep the underline on your menu items, you also need to add `text-decoration:underline;` to those span tags :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/mL6cw4at/2/)**

Comment: the fiddle was just for demonstration the text-decoration wount be displayed in my project but thanks again!

Comment: @StevenWeb note that I also changed `animation-fill-mode: none;` on  `.tr-up` to `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` but I think that was a typo in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try the add iteration count

```
animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

It will be possible

Comment: tryied your solution but there where no changes! thanks for your help!